# Combinatorics problem: How many ways to assign elements between two identical sets (with restriction)

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have two identical sets of a certain size, e.g. $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$.

I want to assign each element of $A$ to an element of $B$. Each element of $B$ can only be assigned once. Also: It is not allowed that an element of $A$ gets assigned to itself in $B$. I'm trying to calculate how many solutions exist given the size of the set.

In the above example there would be 2 solutions: $(1,2)$ $(2,3)$ $(3,1)$ and $(1,3)$ $(2,1)$ $(3,2)$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: Perfect, thanks!